# Javascript question: Cannot add eventlistener for event loadstart on body of html page

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I am trying to add eventlistener for event loadstart on body of html page but it is not working.

Html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Rotate Text</title>
        <script src="rotate_text.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript code (rotate_text.js):

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

function populate_body() {
    alert("Called");
} // end of populate_body

// body.onloadstart = populate_body(); // ====> THIS WORKS
body.addEventListener("loadstart", populate_body); // ====> THIS DOESN'T WORK
```

Why is addEventListener for event loadstart on body not working? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `populate_body()` immediately when you assign it, that's why it worked :)

```js
body.onloadstart = populate_body();
```

Answer (score 0):

The loadStart event occurs when the browser starts looking for the specified media and it can not applied on body element.

```
// body.onloadstart = populate_body(); // ====> THIS WORKS
```

This line of code doesn't add event listener, it shows the alert because you have called populate_body() function.

I'm not sure but maybe onload event is what is you are looking for.

```
function myFunction() {
 alert('body element loaded')
}
document.body.onload = myFunction;
```

Comment: Better to prefer using `document.body.addEventListener('load', callback)` for event listening.